# R: test if user-defined function argument is of class 'logical'

Tags: r

Given a dummy user-defined R function `foo`:

```
foo <- function(tree_format, rooted=TRUE){
    match.arg(tree_format, choices = c('nwk', 'nxs'))    

}
```

If I try to feed an incorrect choice to the function, as follows, I get a meaningful error:

```
foo('bar')
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in match.arg(tree_format, choices = c("nwk", "nxs")) : 
  'arg' should be one of “nwk”, “nxs”
```

I want to do the same for the `rooted` parameter, but I want to ensure that it is of class logical and only of the choices `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  How can I achieve this in `R` so that if I feed the function `foo('nwk', 'bar')` I see an error that `arg` for the `rooted` parameter should be a logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**`stopifnot()`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/stopifnot) and [**`is.logical()`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/logical):

```
foo <- function(a, root = TRUE) {
  stopifnot(is.logical(root), !is.na(root))
  print(a)
}

foo("test212")
foo("test123", FALSE)
foo("test", 123)
```

This will yield an error once the last call is hit.